# Return up to the first three words

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

Trying to find a way to return the first three words in R. I tried the word function in string_r but it only returns the first three words if the sentence has at least three words. e.g.,

```
sentences <- c("Jane saw a cat", "Jane sat down", "Jane sat", "Jane")

word(sentences, 1, 3)
```

This returns `Jane saw a`, `Jane sat down`, `NA`, `NA`

I would like it to return the first three words, even if the sentence has one or two words. So the output I am looking for is:

This returns `Jane saw a`, `Jane sat down`, `Jane Sat`, `Jane`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) stringr** Count the number of words in each component of the input and use that or 3, whichever is less, as the number of words to return.

```
library(stringr)
word(sentences, end = pmin(str_count(sentences, "\\w+"), 3))
## [1] "Jane saw a"    "Jane sat down" "Jane sat"      "Jane"
```

**2) stringr solution 2** Append some dummy words onto the end, take the first 3 words and trim off any dummies left.

```
sentences %>%
  str_c("@ @ @") %>%
  word(end = 3) %>%
  str_replace(" *@.*", "")
## [1] "Jane saw a"    "Jane sat down" "Jane sat"      "Jane"
```

**3a) Base R**  The same idea as (1) can be translated to base R like this:

```
Word <- function(x, end) do.call("paste", read.table(text = x, fill = TRUE)[1:end])

unname(Vectorize(Word)(sentences, end = pmin(lengths(strsplit(sentences, " ")), 3)))
## [1] "Jane saw a"    "Jane sat down" "Jane sat"      "Jane"
```

**3b)** The same idea as (2) can be translated to base R like this. `Word` is from (3a).

```
sentences |>
  paste("@ @ @") |>
  Word(end = 3) |>
  sub(pattern = " *@.*", replacement = "")
## [1] "Jane saw a"    "Jane sat down" "Jane sat"      "Jane"
```

### Update

(1) is simplified and the old (1) is now (2).  (3a) and (3b) are now Base R counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

We can split and get the words

```
sapply(strsplit(sentences, " "), \(x) paste(head(x, 3), collapse=" "))
```

-output

```
[1] "Jane saw a"    "Jane sat down" "Jane sat"      "Jane"
```

---

Or use a regex

```
trimws( sub("^((\\w+\\s+){1,3}).*", "\\1", sentences))
```

-output

```
[1] "Jane saw a" "Jane sat"   "Jane"       "Jane"
```

---

If we want to use `word`, then it may need a `coalesce`

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(3:1,  word, string = sentences, start = 1) %>%
    exec(coalesce, !!!.)
[1] "Jane saw a"    "Jane sat down" "Jane sat"      "Jane"
```